# update table error in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle11g

When I try to run the following script, I get an error:

```
update my_employees_above_avg set (employee_id, first_name, last_name, salary) =
(select employee_id, first_name, last_name, (salary + 100) NewSalary
from my_employees_above_avg
where last_name like '%b%');
```

following error appears:

Error starting at line 40 in command:

```
update my_employees_above_avg set (employee_id, first_name, last_name, salary) =
(select employee_id, first_name, last_name, (salary + 100) NewSalary
from my_employees_above_avg
where last_name like '%b%')
```

Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Please suggest what or why it is giving me the error or how I can resolve this error.

Thanks,

Comment: have yo tried ((salary + 100) NewSalary)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to update the `salary` field in your `my_employees_above_avg` table for each record whose `last_name` is like '%b%', then this should be what you're looking for:

```
update my_employees_above_avg 
set salary = salary + 100
where last_name like '%b%'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1be5b/1)

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your query is that you are trying to update columns `employee_id, first_name, last_name, salary` in all the rows of table and your sub query is returning multiple rows. So oracle can't decide which resulted row to update in columns. Its very much logical.

For example, i want to update Department for all employees in table and my sub query returns 3 departments. Now there is no way to decide which value of sub query to update in table. Hence an error will be thrown.

Solution will be to ensure sub query returns single row.

Also if aim just to update salary then other answers explains the right way to do it.